# Reduce GAE hrd(db) read operation counts

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

To reduce GAE Python usage cost, I want to optimize DB read operation. Do you have any suggestions?

I can't understand why GAE shows quite a lot DB read operation than I thought. If you can give general logic how GAE counts DB read operation it also should be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the full breakdown of what a high-level operation (get, query, put, delete, ...) costs in low-level operations (small, read, write) here - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing (scroll down about half way).

I highly recommend using [AppStats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats) to help track down where your read operations are coming from.  One big thing to watch out for is not to use the `offset` option with `.fetch()` for pagination, as this just skips results, but still costs reads.  That means if you do `.fetch(10, offset=20)`, it will cost you 30 reads.  You want to use [query cursors](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#cursors) instead.

Another optimization is to fetch by key ([`.get(keys)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get)) vs querying, which will only cost 1 read operation, as opposed to querying which cost 1 read for the query + 1 read for each entity returned (so a query with 1 entity returned cost 2 reads, but a `.get()` for that same entity would only cost 1 read.  You might also want to look at using [projection queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#projection), which cost 1 read for the query, but only 1 small per projected entity retrieved (*note:* all properties projected must be indexed).

Also, if you're not already, you should be using the [NDB API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) which automatically [caches](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache) fetches and will help reduce your read operations.  Along with the official docs, the [NDB cheat sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/edit) by Rodrigo and Guido is a great way to transition from ext.db to ndb.

There are some good tips under *Managing Datastore Usage* here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/managing-resources

Lastly, you might also be interested in using [gae_mini_profiler](https://github.com/kamens/gae_mini_profiler), which provides convenient access to AppStats for the current request, as well as other helpful profiling and logging information.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say why without seeing your code but if you're not already, use memcache to save on db reads.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache